# single action for component within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I have one `<div>` in which I will be having multiple components, at first if I click at any component, the corresponding action should be triggered and after that no other component click event within that div should not trigger unless otherwise the mouse moves out of the `<div>` borderline and again comes back in.

I have used `.one()` JQuery function , but that prevents further click

Can anyone tell me some solution for this

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qx5yxe6/)**

**html**

```
<div class='parent' style="width:100px;border:2px solid blue">
    <button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
    <a href="#">Click Me Too</a>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myButton").one("click", function(){
         console.log('button click....');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could craft some manual re-attaching of the event handler. Here is an example

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    attachHandle = function() {
        $('#myButton').one('click', function(){
             console.log('clicked....');
        });
    }

    $('.parent').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('#myButton').off('one');
        attachHandle();
    });

    attachHandle();
});
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6oacu58e/)

### Edit 1

To make this slightly more generic, here is a way to apply this logic to `n` elements within `.parent`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    attachHandle = function() {        
        $('.parent').children().each(function(){
            $(this).one('click', function(){
                 console.log('clicked....');
            });
        });
    }

    $('.parent').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).children().each(function(){
            $(this).off('one')
        })
        attachHandle();
    });
    attachHandle();
});
```

### [Updated JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/49yxryp7/)

### Edit 2

To allow one `click` per sibling element within `.Parent`, refer to the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    attachHandle = function() {        
        $('.parent').children().each(function(){
            $(this).one('click', function(){
                $(this).siblings().off('click');
                 console.log('clicked....');
            });
        });
    }

    $('.parent').on('mouseleave', function() {
        attachHandle();
    });
    attachHandle();
});
```

### [Third JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbuzz2u9/)

Comment: @AlexMan I have updated answer with a generic solution. Please check this out and give feedback I'll happily work through this with you

Comment: in the updated one the issue is that all the components within the div is having one single click event, actually I want one one click event to be allowed at once for any component within the div

Comment: @AlexMan I have tried to update the question to address your needs. Please let me know if this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly:

As i gathered you want to be able to click again after you leave the parent div.

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8qx5yxe6/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var clickable = true;

 $("#myButton").on("click", function(){
  if(clickable) {
        console.log('clicked....');
      clickable = false;
  }

});

$(".parent").on("mouseleave", function() {
      clickable = true;
});
});
```

Comment: Thargor can you come for a chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: Do you have any updation for this in respect to the chat we had